# I have a question about MPI_Sendrecv sentence. Which is the meaning than dest an source process are the same?

Tags: mpi

In the below sentence the dest an source process are the same (0), what is the using of this?

```
MPI_Sendrecv(A,1,filas_ciclicas,0,0,Alocal,k*N,MPI_DOUBLE,
                 0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Comment: exchange data between processes (with a one liner and without a race condition)